# text formatting fails in \item[]

Tags: itemize, description, typefaces

Consider this script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[\textsc{Point} A] description of \textsc{Point} A.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

As can be seen the use of `\textsc` has been ineffective in `\item[]`. Is there a solution?

Comment: Computer Modern, by default, doesn't have bold small caps. LaTeX complains: ``Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc' undefined``. You have to use a font with bold small caps... Apparently if you load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` it works.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, you are encouraged to supply an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Computer Modern font doesn't have a Small Caps font shape by default. Compiling your example, or even this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\scshape{Point A}}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX complains:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/bx/n' instead on input line 4.
```

Changing the font encoding to `T1`, however, gives you access to this font shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\scshape{\textbf{Point A}}
\end{document}
```